# how to add to string degree symbol

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

Trying to print degree (°) symbol

```
t = chr(176).encode('ascii')
qp.drawText(QtCore.QPoint(50, 45), str(self.setText))
print t
```

but getting error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to add # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- at the top of file but no luck. 
P.S. I tried to find out on google but not working for me.

EDIT: 
as @Achilles says :

```
t = u"\u00b0"
qp.drawText(QtCore.QPoint(50, 45), str(self.setText)+t)
```

Thank you

Comment: always add in question full error message (Traceback) - there is inforamtion which line makes problem - `encode()` or `print` ?

Comment: did you try without `encode` ?

Comment: Your first attempt fails because you are adding a Unicode character to your string **but** specifiy you want its ASCII representation - which is an error. Your second attempt fails because you add a character to your string **but** you ask to encode it as UTF8. Consider not trying to tell the string functions what to do.

Comment: @Rad Lexus thank you for explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for degree symbol:

```
  t = u"\u00b0"
  qp.drawText(QtCore.QPoint(50, 45), str(self.setText)+t)
```

Comment: Happy coding ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this line at the top of your source

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```